# Ruby/Heroku "no such load"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

My Heroku app recently crashed after a minor cosmetic change (just added media requests in my css for phone viewing).  This resulted in a "no such file to load" error which appear to be quite common but they all seem to have a different solution so I'll post mine.  The file in question is:

```
/app/app/assets/images/config/environment (LoadError)
```

Here is the stack trace with the error at the top:

```
2015-02-24T18:23:12.318754+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require': No such file to load -- /app/app/assets/images/config/environment (LoadError)
2015-02-24T18:23:12.318769+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:348:in `require_or_load'
2015-02-24T18:23:12.312235+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2015-02-24T18:23:12.318758+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
2015-02-24T18:23:12.318763+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
2015-02-24T18:23:12.318765+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
2015-02-24T18:23:12.318766+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
2015-02-24T18:23:12.318768+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
2015-02-24T18:23:12.318771+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:307:in `depend_on'
2015-02-24T18:23:12.318773+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
2015-02-24T18:23:12.318775+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:468:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2015-02-24T18:23:12.318776+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:467:in `each'
2015-02-24T18:23:12.318778+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:467:in `block in eager_load!'
2015-02-24T18:23:12.318793+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2015-02-24T18:23:12.318807+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2015-02-24T18:23:12.318822+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
2015-02-24T18:23:12.318824+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:50:in `app'
2015-02-24T18:23:12.318829+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
2015-02-24T18:23:12.318831+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
2015-02-24T18:23:12.318832+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
2015-02-24T18:23:12.318833+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
2015-02-24T18:23:12.318835+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2015-02-24T18:23:12.318836+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `require'
2015-02-24T18:23:12.318784+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:58:in `each'
2015-02-24T18:23:12.318790+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2015-02-24T18:23:12.318794+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2015-02-24T18:23:12.318799+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2015-02-24T18:23:12.318801+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2015-02-24T18:
```

Currently using rails 4.1.4, I made no change to the config.ru/environment.rb files and a change was not made to my Gemfile.  Not sure what is going on.

Comment: It looks as if `app/assets/images` was injected into `app/config/environment` to create the mangled path `/app/app/assets/images/config/environment`. Considering those path names and your recently made "cosmetic changes," I'd say double-check your changes. Better yet, explain your changes in the question (with code).

Comment: If you could post `git log --stat` for commits since last release it could help (may be just files listing if you don't want to share your commit messages)